# How do I use the dojo constraints object to customize the text input field for an IP address in my dojo TextBox or NumberTextBox

Tags: javascript, input, dojo, dijit.form, dojo.gridx

How do I use the constraints object to customize the text input field for an IP address in my dojo TextBox or NumberTextBox. Or is there another object I should be using to do this where the user has to type a IP address correctly.

I simply want to create a input field for users to input an IP address which requires something like this: `pattern:'min:1,max255.min:0,max255.min:0,max255.min:0,max255'`

I believe my current problem is that I'm trying to use the NumberTextBox and it has constraints that are overriding my constraints.

I would really like to know what all constraint options I have available but the documentation on dojo constraints I found was deprecated and the link replaced pointed to DateTimeBox. :|

Here is a snippet of my code:

```
cellWidget.outProActFeedsDestAddr.set('constraints', {pattern:'min:1,max255.min:0,max255.min:0,max255.min:0,max255'});
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While IP addresses are numeric in a sense, NumberTextBox is really intended for typical single numeric values, so that's not really an option here.  You've potentially got a couple of choices:

1. Use ValidationTextBox and give it an appropriate `regExp` (note that Dijit expects a string for this property, and applies `^` and `$` around it itself), or a `validator` function (there is a `dojox/validate/regexp.ipAddress` that you could potentially play with)
2. Write a form widget that combines 4 `NumberTextBox` instances into one `value` (I'm not sure whether the grid would throw a wrench into the works with regard to tab stops with this approach)

Comment: Perfect - thanks! I'm trying to get my regex to work though - nothing seems to be working. Here is one I tried: `cellWidget.ipColumn.set('regExp', "^([01]?\d\d?|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.([01]?\d\d?|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.([01]?\d\d?|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.([01]?\d\d?|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])$");`

Comment: I posted another question on getting the regex working: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29216116/how-do-i-get-my-regular-expression-code-working-on-my-dojo-cellwidget-object

Comment: So yes - ValidationTextBox and the correct regex fixed this for me. I used this regex (needed the double \\ I believe to get it to work in my dojo ValidationTextBox): `([01]?\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])[.]([01]?\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])[.]([01]?\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])[.]([01]?\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])`